# What MySQL column type to save the value of PHP's time() function result?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a PHP PDO Database Class that I am trying to modify and use for my needs.

One of the features it has is the option to auto-update `created_+at` and `updated_at` DB columns.

This is similar to Laravel as models in Laravel have the option of doing this.  Luckily though Laravel handles creating the DB columns for you.

IN my case I have to create these columns and the PHP class will handle updating them.

The class uses the PHP `time()` function to update these columns.

After some reasearch to see what type of columns Laravel uses for its timestamp `created_at` and `updated_at` columns I found it uses a MySQL `timestamp` column type.

So I proceeded to test my PDO class with a DB table that has a `created_at` column of the `timestamp` type with this query below and got error message:

```
INSERT INTO `timeclock`.`password_reminders` 
    (`email`, `token`, `created_at`) 
VALUES 
    ('jaso33n.davis.fl@gmail.com', '5432', '1455771891'),
    ('jas6756on.davis.fl@gmail.com', '12345', '1455771898');
```

I get this message in phpMyAdmin:

```
2 rows inserted.
Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'created_at' at row 1
Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'created_at' at row 2
```

The PHP class uses `time()` to generate values like this: `value like this:`1455771305``

So what type of DB column should I use for these fields?

Comment: what you're inserting there is a [unix timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php). mysql's [`timestamp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) format is different `1970-01-01 00:00:01` just edit the class that you have to fit it in your table column

Comment: use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s','1455771898')`

Comment: question updated to be more brief to the point.  So as the PHP class uses the result of PHP's `time()` I just need to know what type of MySQL column to create that will best store its value.

Comment: Did you look in the Laravel source or the source for this ORM you're using? There has to be mention of the column type in one of those. `time()` returns an `int`. What column type are you using that it gets truncated?

Comment: `datetime` will best I think

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain The goal is to update the MySQL table column type and not touch the PHP in this case

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain I'll give it a try thanks - UPDATE, that wont work as the result is `0000-00-00 00:00:00` when saving new values in my time() format

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the `time()` function's raw value, which is simply a number of seconds passed since 1970-01-01. You should use a standard DATETIME column time, and convert your timestamp using `FROM_UNIXTIME()` MySQL function as suggested in the answer below. Keeping dates as dates and not timestamps is a) more logical and b) brings many other benefits in the long term.

Comment: If you're keen, however, to store your date values as timestamps instead, a simple INT column would do.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the integer string '1455771891' with from_unixtime('1455771891').

```
mysql> select from_unixtime('1455771305');
+-----------------------------+
| from_unixtime('1455771305') |
+-----------------------------+
| 2016-02-18 12:55:05.000000  |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

using time function insert time in mysql column

mysql_select_db('ecommerce', $con);

$time= time('h:i:s A');

mysql_query('INSERT INTO tbl_users (id,firstName,lastName,time) VALUES (35,"asd","pqr", "'.$time.'")');